# Network/Socket Connection Issue

Tags: tcp, dhcp, bridge

**Problem**
Socket Connection between 192.168.1.1(Server) and 192.168.1.12(Client) can NOT be established (See Fig. 1).

**Tests**
Test 1: "Ping"
`ping 192.168.1.2 -S 192.168.1.1` -> Success
`ping 192.168.1.12 -S 192.168.1.11` -> Success
`ping 192.168.1.12 -S 192.168.1.1` -> Fail

Test 2: "Socket Connection"
Socket Connection between 192.168.1.1(Server) and 192.168.1.2(Client) can be be established.
Datas have been received and sent successfully.
Socket Connection between 192.168.1.1(Server) and 192.168.1.12(Client) can NOT be established.
BeginAccept's callback at SocketSever has NEVER been called.

Test 3: "Alternate Endpoint Devices"
Socket Connection between 192.168.1.1(Server) and 192.168.1.2(Client) can be be established.
Socket Connection between 192.168.1.1(Server) and 192.168.1.12(Client) can NOT be established.
Therefore, Both of Endpoint Devices work finely (Actually they are same products)

Test 4: "Another network structure"
On another network structure, all works finely (See Fig. 2).
However i can not take this solution because i can not put a HUB between Left and Right USB-ETHERNET.

**My assumption**
This problem caused by that both networks are isolated and can't interact each other.
If there is any Windows application works like "HUB", it might resolve this case.

**Any suggestions or solutions?**
Thank you for helping.

[image: Fig. 1]
[image: Fig. 2]

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as are host configurations. You are missing the part about how the two lines in figure 1 connect. Are you using a switch? You need to explain this in more detail.

Comment: Sorry for inappropriate topic. Do you know where i should post..? Stack Overflow is more proper? Anyway, i'm not using switching hub. PC <-> USB-ETHERNET <-> LAN Cable <-> USB-ETHERNET <-> Endpoint. There are two pairs of it.

Comment: Then this appears to be a host configuration problem, and that, unfortunately, is off-topic here. You could try to ask this on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup #1 doesn't work because you have *two* networks, and both are 192.168.1.0/24. It works in setup #2 because there's only one network.

The simplest option -- if you *must* persist with Fig. 1 -- is to setup the two USB interfaces as a "bridge". (Desktop versions of Windows won't act as a router -- connection sharing isn't routing.)

Comment: Thank you for helping. Now i'm currently studying how to make a bridge on Windows... If anything progressed, i'll report to here...